# How to load Validation error dynamically in Angular/HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

I've a form control where user has to enter Id. I've validated submit button to enable only when field is filled with value(only numbers).

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Movie_Id" name="Movid" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" required/>
<input type="submit" value="Add" ng-disabled="adduserform.$invalid" data-ng-click="Save()"/>
```

But I want to notify user dynamically when he tries to enter alphabets like "You should only enter Numbers" because user may not know the reason why Submit button is disabled when he enters alphabets.

Comment: Read the doc: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/directive/input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you could use `$error` property of form of field level `$error` property.

```
<form name="adduserform">
  <input type="text" ng-model="Movie_Id" name="Movid" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" required/>
  <span ng-show="adduserform.Movid.$invalid"> Only number are allowed</span>
  <input type="submit" value="Add" ng-disabled="adduserform.$invalid" data-ng-click="Save()"/>
</form>
```

In above example I had used `adduserform.Movid.$invalid` which will tell us that `Movid` is valid field or not, & if it doesn't valid then validation message will shown.

**Update**

As we want two different errors to be show we could use `$error.required` to get required error & `$error.pattern` to get patterns match or not

**Markup**

```
<span style="color:red" ng-show="adduserform.Movid.$dirty && adduserform.Movid.$invalid"> <br /> 
  <span ng-show="adduserform.Movid.$error.required" class="spnmsg">Field must not be empty</span> 
  <span ng-show="adduserform.Movid.$error.pattern">Only Numbers</span> 
</span>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WF6lJ7SLucNeJHhueyrS?p=preview)

Comment: thnks for ur code.......but the scenario is quite like
1). If user let control empty then "Field must not be empty" should appear
2). if user enters alphabets then above error should disappear n "Only numbers" have to be shown.

Its like 1 & 2 should only appear based on input from user.....

`<input type="text" ng-model="Movie_Id" class="form-control" name="Movid" placeholder="Movie Id" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" required title="Enter Movie Id" />`

Comment: `<span style="color:red" ng-show="adduserform.Movid.$dirty && adduserform.Movid.$invalid">
                            <br />
                            <span ng-show="adduserform.Movid.$error.required" class="spnmsg">Field must not be empty</span>
                            <span ng-show="adduserform.Movid.$invalid">Only Numbers</span>
                        </span>`
But here both errors are appearing together...how could i overcome it....

Comment: @VinoSpartan you number error should look at `adduserform.Movid.$error.pattern` will show an error, see my updated answer with plunkr

Comment: thnks a lot bro......Magic works......how could i be in touch as i'm building a page with angular........as new one, quite need guidance......

Comment: @VinoSpartan go through this http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/ & please do upvote if it does helped you, Thanks :-)